# Import chance.js to react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to import chance js into my current native react project but it returns error.

[image]

solved

```
npm install chance
then in your app

// Load Chance
var Chance = require('chance');

// Instantiate Chance so it can be used
var chance = new Chance();

// Use Chance here.
var my_random_string = chance.string();
```

Comment: did you download it with npm ?

Comment: yes i solved...

Answer (score 3):

```
import Chance from 'chance';
const chance = new Chance();

chance.string(); // "x(gAy#yo0^"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using:

`import Chance from 'chance';`

-> `!NB Chance` with a caps 'C'

then using `chance` with a lowercase `'c'` works fine ...

Comment: That does not work. You will have to instantiate chance as in `let chance = new Chance()`